# Hide console windows in C++ Builder

Tags: compilation, c++builder

I am using Embarcadero C++ 10.2 ‘Tokyo’ command line Compiler as a small footprint compiler, it is distributed in a compressed form and easily 'portable'.

I am trying to implement this small `Close Tray` program using Win32 API.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  mciSendString("Set CDAudio Door Closed Wait", 0, 0, 0); 
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it using `bcc32c Close.cpp` works fine but the console window appears as it should when the executable is double clicked.
Is there a way to cancel its presence like the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` that is used with Microsoft compiler.

Update: For instance in order to do that in `Digital Mars`, I compile the source file using `sc source.c` then use its linker `Optlink` like that

`link source.obj,,,winmm.lib /subsystem:windows`

because compiling it isn't enough in Digital Mars, it needs linking to `winmm.lib` while Embarcadero's compiler does that automatically.

**Update 2:** I also saw an option `-tW` to make the taget executable for Windows but it didn't work so is using `bcc32x -mwindows`  since it is based on Clang and still didn't get the result needed.

Comment: The correct way to handle this is to make a GUI app (`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` with a `WinMain()`) instead of a console app (`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` with a `main()`), and just don't create any UI in your code. But how you make a GUI app with the command-line compiler, I'm not sure. You could use `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)`, but it is not good to hide a console window you don't own.

Comment: @RemyLebeau your suggestion would make the console windows flash and disappear in fraction of seconds, I am looking for a way to disable it completely.

Comment: There is only one way to disable the console properly, and that is to simply not create a console app in the first place. I would suggest creating a window-less GUI app in the C++Builder IDE and then enable its output to show the parameters it invokes the compiler with, and then you can port those settings to the command-line compiler (or, you can simply compile the IDE project as-is on the command-line using [MSBuild](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MSBuild) and let it handle the complexities of the compiler for you)

Comment: I do not have the IDE onIy the command line compiler, guess that you're right, this one is more restrictive than the other ones, if it isn't a Windows application it won't compile as one. MSBuild might be better but it doesn't come as a compressed portable folder, second it might add `msvcrt` dependency if you don't do a static linking.

Comment: C++Builder apps don’t use msvcrt

Comment: I am talking about MSBuild.

Comment: MSBuild is just a build chain framework. It just invokes whatever compiler and linker are configured. What is important is the runtime that the compiler and linker use, and C++Builder’s runtime doesn’t use msvcrt. That is a Visual Studio dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int CmdShow) {
               
  mciSendString("Set CDAudio Door Closed Wait", 0, 0, 0);

  
  return 0;
}
```

On command line compiler it compiles with

```
bcc32 -W winmain.c
```

I don't know if the switch works on your compiler.

Update: The WinMain parameters can be omitted if not needed.

```
int WINAPI WinMain() {
```

Comment: It works, but some notes, you forget a letter, `Set CDAudio Door close**d**`, the second one, the flag is `-tW` with `bcc32c` since `bcc32` doesn't exist in this version, also the size of the executable is 61KB compared with 30KB for GCC and 12KB for Digital Mars.

Comment: Thanks, edited the answer with change to command string.